# Printing unicode characters c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi and trying to print unicode characters with something like this:

test.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char a=L'\u1234';
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with g++, I get this warning:

```
test.cpp: In function "int main()":
test.cpp:4:9: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

And the output is:

```
4
```

Also, this is not in the GUI and my distribution is raspbian wheezy if that is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the local before you can use it, unless your native system is using it.

```
 setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
```

To print the stirng use `wcout` instead of `cout`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
    wchar_t a=L'\u1234';
    std::wcout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Uh, yes, I missed to change that as well. Fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

As a reference to one of the previous answers, you should not use wchar_t and w* functions on Linux. POSIX APIs use `char` data type and most POSIX implementations use UTF-8 as a default encoding. Quoting the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011)

> 5.3.3 Sizeof
>
> **sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char)** are **1**.
>   The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. [ Note: in particular, sizeof(bool),
>   sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and **sizeof(wchar_t)** are
>   **implementation-defined**. 74 — end note ]

UTF-8 uses 1-byte code units and up to 4 code units to represent a code point, so `char` is enough to store UTF-8 strings, though to manipulate them you are going to need to find out if a specific code unit is represented by multiple bytes and build your processing logic with that in mind. `wchar_t` has an implementation-defined size and the Linux distributions that I have seen have a size of 4 bytes for this data type.

There is another problem that the mapping from the source code to the object code may transform your encoding in a compiler-specific way:

> 2.2 Phases of translation
>
> Physical **source file characters** are **mapped**, in an
>   **implementation-defined manner**, to the basic source character set
>   (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if
>   necessary.

Anyway, in the most cases you don't have any conversions on your source code so the strings that you put into `char*` stay unmodified. If you encode your source code with UTF-8 then you are going to have bytes representing UTF-8 code units in your `char*`s.

As for your code example: it does not work as expected because 1 `char` has a size of 1 byte. Unicode *code points* may require several (up to 4) UTF-8 *code units* to be serialized (for UTF-8 `1 code unit == 1 byte`). You can see [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/1234/) that `U+1234` requires three bytes `E1 88 B4` when UTF-8 is used and, therefore, cannot be stored in a single char. If you modify your code as follows it's going to work just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char* str = "\u1234";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is going to output `ሴ` though you may see nothing depending on your console and the installed fonts, the actual bytes are going to be there. Note that with double quotes you also have a `\0` terminator in-memory.

You could also use an array, but not with single quotes since you would need a different data type (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) for more information):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char* str = "\u1234";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // size of the array is 4 because \0 is appended
    // for string literals and there are 3 bytes
    // needed to represent the code point
    char arr[4] = "\u1234";
    std::cout.write(arr, 3);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is going to be `ሴ` on the two different lines in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use wide characters:

try with:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t a = L'\u1234';
    wcout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why must we use wide characters?

Comment: @dieram3, no, you shouldn't. Firstly, wchar_t has nothing to do with Unicode - it is merely enough to store a 4-byte code unit on most Linux distributions and otherwise is implementation-defined. POSIX APIs use single-byte per code point encodings such as UTF-8 so you need to use plain 'char' data type. wchar_t usage for working with Unicode comes from Windows

Comment: @0x499602D2
I would rather advice not to use wide characters on Linux, please take a look at my answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040393/printing-unicode-characters-c-linux/32413257#32413257