# wofstream not writing Japanese Characters in file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, wofstream

I'm trying to write Japanese to a file using wofstream and wstring. Unfortunately, wofstream doesn't write Japanese characters to the file when compiled with `g++` or `clang++` (in `WSL` and `Windows 10`) with no additional flags.

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::wofstream file("file.txt");
    std::wstring str = L"Onee-chan, Ohayou!";
    file << str;
}
```

file.txt

```
Onee-chan, Ohayou!
```

But,

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::wofstream file("file.txt");
    std::wstring str = L"お姉ちゃん、おはよう！";
    file << str;
}
```

`file.txt` has `0 bytes` of size.

## **BUT** when compiled with **MSVC** with the following code,

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream file("file.txt");
    std::string str = "お姉ちゃん、おはよう！";
    file << str;
}
```

**file.txt** has:
`お姉ちゃん、おはよう！`

Want my application to run on both linux and Windows. It works on windows with `msvc` (using `string`, `char` and `fstream`s [that's good]). I don't think `MSVC` is on linux, therefore I tried using `wstring`, `wchat_t` and `wfstream`s with `g++` (in `WSL` and Windows cmd) but they don't write Japanese to the files.

### Any suggestions on how to get through this.

#### (For Example: `msvc` like settings for `g++`(preferred) or any changes in the code(not preferred))

Comment: Adding `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` at the start of `main` fixed it for me. So does `file.imbue(std::locale(""));` (after you define `file` of course).

Comment: Your code works as is for me on windows `g++ (Rev9, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0`

Comment: Does this have to be using wide strings with GCC? Making everything UTF-8 and using a regular `std::string` (or something that actually conveys that info) seems like the more workable option.

Comment: AFAIK [`std::wstring` is not the Unicode string in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413257/8423261), try using `std::string` and `std::ofstream` instead and see if that makes a change.